# SslStream does not call BeginRead or ReadAsync of InnerStream in .NET Core 2.1+ (contrary to .NET Framework and .NET Core 2.0)

Tags: c#, .net-core

I found that SslStream in .NET Core 2.1/2.2 does not call BeginRead or ReadAsync of InnerStream when SslStream's BeginRead or ReadAsync are called. For me, it seems to be a bug in SslStream implementation but maybe it's the intended behavior now?

The code below makes a connection to SMTP server smtp-mail.outlook.com at port 587 and then switches the connection to TLS with a STARTTLS command. MyStream is a wrapper around NetworkStream which I pass to SslStream.

usings:

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Text;
```

MyStream class:

```
public class MyStream : NetworkStream
{
    public MyStream(TcpClient tc) : base(tc.Client)
    {
    }

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        int bytesRead = 0;

        try
        {
            bytesRead = base.Read(buffer, offset, count);
        }
        finally
        {
        }
        return bytesRead;
    }

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        try
        {
            base.Write(buffer, offset, count);
        }
        finally
        {
        }
    }

    public override void WriteByte(byte value)
    {
        try
        {
            base.WriteByte(value);
        }
        finally
        {
        }
    }

    public override IAsyncResult BeginRead(byte[] buffer, int offset, int size, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
    {
        try
        {
            return base.BeginRead(buffer, offset, size, callback, state);
        }
        finally
        {
        }
    }

    public override int EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        int bytesRead = 0;

        try
        {
            bytesRead = base.EndRead(asyncResult);
        }
        finally
        {
        }
        return bytesRead;
    }

    public override IAsyncResult BeginWrite(byte[] buffer, int offset, int size, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
    {

        try
        {
            return base.BeginWrite(buffer, offset, size, callback, state);
        }
        finally
        {
        }
    }

    public override void EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        try
        {
            base.EndWrite(asyncResult);
        }
        finally
        {
        }
    }

    public override Task<int> ReadAsync(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.Factory.FromAsync<int>(BeginRead(buffer, offset, count, null, null), EndRead);
    }

    public override Task WriteAsync(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.Factory.FromAsync(BeginWrite(buffer, offset, count, null, null), EndWrite);
    }
}
```

Main method:

```
public async static Task Main(string[] args)
{
    TcpClient tc = new TcpClient();
    await tc.ConnectAsync("smtp-mail.outlook.com", 587);
    MyStream ms = new MyStream(tc);
    byte[] response = new byte[64*1024];
    int n;
    string command;
    byte[] request;
    n = await ms.ReadAsync(response, 0, response.Length);
    command = "EHLO domain\r\n";
    request = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(command);
    await ms.WriteAsync(request, 0, request.Length);
    n = await ms.ReadAsync(response, 0, response.Length);
    Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(response, 0, n));
    command = "STARTTLS\r\n";
    request = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(command);
    await ms.WriteAsync(request, 0, request.Length);
    n = await ms.ReadAsync(response, 0, response.Length);
    Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(response, 0, n));
    SslStream ssl = new SslStream(ms);
    await ssl.AuthenticateAsClientAsync("smtp-mail.outlook.com");
    command = "RSET\r\n";
    request = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(command);
    await ssl.WriteAsync(request, 0, request.Length);
    n = await ssl.ReadAsync(response, 0, response.Length);
    Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(response, 0, n));
    command = "QUIT\r\n";
    request = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(command);
    await ssl.WriteAsync(request, 0, request.Length);
    n = await ssl.ReadAsync(response, 0, response.Length);
    Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(response, 0, n));
    ssl.Dispose();
    tc.Close();
}
```

In .NET Core 2.1+, MyStream.BeginRead, MyStream.EndRead and MyStream.ReadAsync will not be called after ssl.AuthenticateAsClientAsync line.

In .NET Core 2.0 and .NET Framework, they are called as they should be.

EDIT:
I now tried it with the latest Visual Studio 2019 and the .NET Core 3.0 Preview 5. The issue remains.

Comment: Possibly related to Span changes? The "core" APIs are no longer the byte-array ones; they'd be the Span ones.

Comment: @StephenCleary Yes, indeed. But is this still a bug with the new design? Because it breaks the existing code.

Comment: Why not [raise an issue](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues) if you want to know if the developers consider it a bug? Note that `NetworkStream` has [special code](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/6d5959cbc7d489406f8f85dba0a42f06d4a0ea9b/src/System.Net.Sockets/src/System/Net/Sockets/NetworkStream.cs#L309) to preserve backwards compatibility with derived classes for the synchronous case, but not the asynchronous case.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Great insight, thanks. I now raised the issue at https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/38198

Comment: It seems to work around the issue I need to derive MyStream from Stream, not from NetworkStream. This way it works with both .NET Core 2.0 and 2.2.